# Ionic Linking to ionic pro error in "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic"

Tags: ionic-framework, deployment, ionic3, mobile-application

I have a problem when I run this command

```
  cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic --save \ --variable APP_ID="6c12fffb" \ --variable CHANNEL_NAME="Production" \ --variable UPDATE_METHOD="background"
```

I get the following error :

[image]

as shown in the image it keeps saying that my app name "zagelosc" is not registered.
It was first ZagelOSC and it said I needed to change the capital letters so i did so but the same error appears.

here is the log error file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'view',
1 verbose cli   '--json' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 silly mapToRegistry name zagelosc
5 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
6 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
7 silly mapToRegistry data { type: 'tag',
7 silly mapToRegistry   registry: true,
7 silly mapToRegistry   where: undefined,
7 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'zagelosc',
7 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'zagelosc',
7 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'zagelosc',
7 silly mapToRegistry   scope: undefined,
7 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
7 silly mapToRegistry   saveSpec: null,
7 silly mapToRegistry   fetchSpec: 'latest',
7 silly mapToRegistry   gitRange: undefined,
7 silly mapToRegistry   gitCommittish: undefined,
7 silly mapToRegistry   hosted: undefined }
8 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/zagelosc
9 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/zagelosc
10 verbose request no auth needed
11 info attempt registry request try #1 at 17:33:47
12 verbose request id ad85b4c81a22e967
13 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zagelosc
14 http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/zagelosc
15 verbose headers { date: 'Tue, 10 Jul 2018 15:33:47 GMT',
15 verbose headers   'content-type': 'application/json',
15 verbose headers   'content-length': '21',
15 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
15 verbose headers   'set-cookie':
15 verbose headers    [ '__cfduid=de2120c1284e564efd4b7db8bd51fd30a1531236825; expires=Wed, 10-Jul-19 15:33:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.registry.npmjs.org; HttpOnly' ],
15 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
15 verbose headers   'cf-cache-status': 'MISS',
15 verbose headers   'cf-ray': '4384172f3fd94149-CAI',
15 verbose headers   'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
15 verbose headers   vary: 'accept-encoding, accept',
15 verbose headers   server: 'cloudflare' }
16 verbose stack Error: Not found : zagelosc
16 verbose stack     at makeError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:314:12)
16 verbose stack     at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:302:14)
16 verbose stack     at Request._callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:216:14)
16 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
16 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
16 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
16 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
16 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
16 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
16 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1085:12)
17 verbose statusCode 404
18 verbose pkgid zagelosc
19 verbose cwd C:\Users\'abc\Desktop\gg\zagelOSC_App
20 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
21 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "view" "--json"
22 verbose node v8.9.3
23 verbose npm  v5.5.1
24 error code E404
25 error 404 Not found : zagelosc
26 error 404
27 error 404 'zagelosc' is not in the npm registry.
28 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
29 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
30 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
31 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: It's better to include your errors as text in the question rather than as an image. You'll more help more quickly if you do.

Comment: thanks @Nick, i updated the post now